# Create, refresh a WPF TreeView and remember expanded nodes without XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, treeview

I am currently upgrading the tool of my predecessor and I'm stuck on a `TreeView` issue. His software analyzed data one time and displayed the results in a `TreeView`. I changed the tool to analyze real-time data and hence the user gets real time results. *Now, I would like the tree view nodes to keep expanded when the user expands it, even after an update.* I know this topic has been discussed several times and I spent hours reading the answers but I never found a solution for my problem.

*The basic problem is:* there is no stable tree any more and currently the tree is just re-created every time. I have no idea about data binding or XAML up to now and few time to learn programming in XAML. Below you can see the code like it was created by my predecessor. I did not change anything up to now, I just recall this method every 2-5 seconds.

Is there an (easy?) way to store the information about expanded nodes anywhere (global?) and re-expand it after refresh or do I really need to get a deeper understanding of WPF first?

```
foreach (Analyzer.ALARM_GROUP alarmGroup in alarmGroupList)
{
    //Display Problem Group
    TreeViewItem groupItem = new TreeViewItem();
    List<String> ListAreas = new List<string>();
    string areas = "";

    //GROUP HEADER
    //display alarm group which contains more than one alarm
    if (alarmGroup.AlarmList.Count > 1)
    {
        groupItem.Header = Convert.ToString(alarmGroup.AlarmList.Count) + " --- " + alarmGroup.AlarmList[0].EventTime + "     " + alarmGroup.AlarmList[0].AlarmText + "\n         "
                    + alarmGroup.AlarmList[alarmGroup.AlarmList.Count - 1].EventTime + "     " + alarmGroup.AlarmList[alarmGroup.AlarmList.Count - 1].AlarmText
                    + " --- " + " AREAS: " + areas;
    }
    else //display alarm group with only one alarm message
    {
        groupItem.Header = Convert.ToString(alarmGroup.AlarmList.Count) + " --- " + alarmGroup.AlarmList[0].EventTime + "     " + alarmGroup.AlarmList[0].AlarmText + " --- " + " AREA: " + areas;
    }

    //HEADLINE of single Alarm Item
    TreeViewItem alarmItem = new TreeViewItem();
    alarmItem.Header = "[EVENTTIME]                           [ALARMTAG] --- [OPCCONDITION] --- [SEVERITY] --- [AREA] --- [ALARMTEXT]";
    alarmItem.FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold;
    groupItem.Items.Add(alarmItem);

    //Display single alarm messages
    foreach (var alarm in alarmGroup.AlarmList)
    {
        alarmItem = new TreeViewItem();
        alarmItem.Header = alarm.EventTime + " --- " + alarm.AlarmTag + " --- " + alarm.Condition + " --- " + alarm.Severity + " --- " + alarm.Area + " --- " + alarm.AlarmText;
        alarmItem.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
        groupItem.Items.Add(alarmItem);
    }

    AlarmPresentationBox.Items.Add(groupItem);
```

Answer (score 6):

> do I really need to get a deeper understanding of WPF first?

I would say Yes, specially in case you are planning to work/support this application for longer period of time; and if you would like to work in WPF in future then it's better to get your hands dirty with XAML and WPF concepts.

Personally, I would never implement this tool this way, instead I would go for MVVM approch as described in following article and make it clean, maintainable and efficient - [Simplifying the WPF TreeView by Using the ViewModel Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode)

> Is there an (easy?) way to store the information about expanded nodes
>   anywhere (global?) and re-expand it after refresh

You can try something like this -

Create a list to store the header(or any unique property/id) of expanded nodes

```
private List<string> expandedNodes = new List<string>();
```

Handle the Expanded and Collapsed event of each node(having child nodes)

```
TreeViewItem alarmItem = new TreeViewItem();
alarmItem.Expanded += OnAlarmItemExpanded;
```

Update the list whenever node is expanded/collapsed -

```
private void OnAlarmItemExpanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem treeNode = sender as TreeViewItem;
    string header = treeNode.Header.ToString();
    if (expandedNodes.Contains(header) == false)
    {
        expandedNodes.Add(header);
    }
}

private void OnAlarmItemCollapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem treeNode = sender as TreeViewItem;
    string header = treeNode.Header.ToString();
    if (expandedNodes.Contains(header))
    {
        expandedNodes.Remove(header);
    }
}
```

Next time whenever you create a TreeViewItem, expand it if it's header(Uniques Id) is present in list -

```
if (expandedNodes.Contains(header))
{
    alarmItem.IsExpanded = true;
}
```

This needs to be done for both groupItem and alarmItem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just tried a different approach by hooking up the complete Tree and storing the nodes and it's status in a dictionary but it did not work. Your approach sounds better. I'm just implementing it.

Comment: Thank you even more. It works perfectly. I should have asked this question 3 days earlier...
About WPF: There are two many other problems to deal with at the moment. When I solved these problems I might "get my hands dirty". For now I try to avoid XAML

Comment: Good Solution. But I'd better use GetHashCode instead. header string is not very unique ID.

Comment: @shj Agree, its mentioned in answer too "Create a list to store the header(_or any **unique** property/id_) of expanded nodes"

Answer (score -1):

CompareTreeViewItem -

```
private void CompareTreeViewItem(TreeViewItem TViewItem1,TreeViewItemTViewItem2)
{
    if ((string)TViewItem1.Header == (string)TViewItem2.Header)
    {
        TViewItem2.IsExpanded = TViewItem1.IsExpanded;

        if (TViewItem1.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < TViewItem1.Items.Count && i < TViewItem2.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                CompareTreeViewItem((TreeViewItem)TViewItem1.Items[i],
                                    (TreeViewItem)TViewItem2.Items[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```